# How to calculate $E(x)$ and $V(x)$ when $g(x)\sim f(g(x))$

Tags: distributions, data-transformation, expected-value, moments

Let assume that we are interested in a variable $x$.

We know that e.g. $g(x)=x^2$, $g(x) \sim Uniform(a,b)$ or any other distribution.

From that I can calculate $E(g(x)) = (a+b)/2$ and $V(g(x))=(b-a)/12$ .

Is there a way to calculate the $E(x)$ and $V(x)$?

I tried to do some research but I do not know how to phrase the question in one phrase or word to search

Comment: Are you asking how to compute moments of $g^{-1}(X)$ where $X$ has a uniform distribution?  Or, as the title suggests, are you asking how to compute moments of $g^{-1}(X)$ when *all* you know are $E(X)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X)$?

Comment: @whuber thank you for the reply. My title is misleading. I am asking how to compute the moments of $g^{-1}(x)$ when x has a known distribution e.g. a uniform.

Comment: I made a try to fix the title after your comment. Thank you again

Comment: You need to assume more about the distribution of $X$.  To see why, let $X$ be any variable for which $g(X)=X^2$ has a uniform distribution on $[a,b]$.  Let $U$ be an independent variable with $\Pr(U=1)=\lambda$ and $\Pr(U=-1)=1-\lambda$. Then $g(XU)=(XU)^2=X^2$ also has a uniform distribution on $[a,b]$. However, $E(XU)=E(X)E(U)=(2\lambda-1)E(X)$ and a comparable expression for the variance show that you cannot conclude much about the mean or variance of $XU$.

Comment: I see your point. I would like to do some further reading to understand that though. Any keyword phrase for searching? Maybe "transformation of random variables?" Thank you again

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=transform%20distribution, http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=delta+method, and http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=jacobian+variable+change, *inter alia*.